# Calling c (compiled file) through c++ program

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have two files **`Posit.c`** and **`HeadPose.cpp`**

- **`Posit.c`**  compiled to  ***`Positnew`***

My question is

- How to call already compiled Positnew like this `system("Positnew");` from HeadPose.cpp

Comment: Are you trying to just run the "Positnew" program, or capture its output?

Comment: -1 but whats the reason...Please clarify...

Comment: Then what's wrong with `system()`? Just give it the complete path to the "Positnew" program.

Comment: Its giving me error saying `Segmentation fault` when I m using `system()`

Comment: If `system` returns `-1`, then check the variable `errno` (from the header file `<errno.h>`), or use the function `strerror(errno)` if you have it to get a string describing the error.

Comment: Can you add the code where you call `system`? Also, it might be that the error comes from Positnew. Learn to use the GDB debugger to see where and why the program crashes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Let me check

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Positnew individually working fine...Even If i will paste all my code it will not be helpful...because I am just doing `system("Positnew");` and getting `Segmentation fault`

Comment: Is Postnew an application or is a c function?

Comment: If the program by itself works, and your call to `system` is as simple as using a simple literal string, then there is something else wrong in your "HeadPose" program. build it with debug flags (add flag -g to gcc) and use [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use c keyword `extern` to declare the function then the linker will make sure that it can be linked either dynamically or statically.

`extern void Positnew()`

Comment: +1...Thanks for the answer bro...I am not getting no errors when I am using that but how do i confirm that its working....Any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: If the application links then it should work. You must know what it is supposed to do you will have to observe the results.

Answer (score 1):

See [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/popen.html). It returns a `FILE*` you can read from or write to, depending on your needs.

```
FILE *posit = popen("Positnew", "r"); 
// read from posit using for example fread
```

Comment: +1 I dont want to read or write.....Please help if you can....Any ways thanks for your time.....